# I would like my subqueries to return more than one value (= for each member), is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

In my website, people can publish articles and like them.

I would like to calculate a level for each member using the number of articles they have published, and the number of likes they received.

I have a request which works fine but for only one member at a time because of subqueries i guess. So for now, I can only do it on their profile page.

And I would like a request for all members to do a Top 3 for my homepage.

Do you have any ideas on how I can resolve this ? I am pretty new in development, so I guess my code is already not that good. Thanks for your answers and suggestions.

```
// this code for one person, works fine
SELECT 
      (select (count(l.idArticle)) as nbLikes 
       from likes as l inner join articles as a on l.idArticle = a.idArticle 
       where a.pseudo ="' . $_SESSION['pseudo']. '") 
       + 
       ( select count(pseudo) as nbArticle 
       from articles and pseudo ="' . $_SESSION['pseudo']. '") 
as sumCount

// code i tried for all member but did not work, saying subqueries have more than one row

SELECT 
       (select (count(l.idArticle)/3) as nbLikes 
       from likes as l inner join articles as a on l.idArticle = a.idArticle 
       group by a.pseudo) 
       + 
       ( select count(pseudo) as nbArticle 
       from articles 
       group by pseudo) 
as sumCount
```

> #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Table structure (Sorry, name of each column in french) :
[Table Article in first - and then table for like. They are quite simple I guess.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtTFm.png)

Table for Like is pretty simple, people can only like or delete their like, they can't dislike.
Link between table Like and Article is made with idArticle.
I have a table for members too, but did not use it here.

Comment: Can you share your table-structure and some example data? Perhaps create a fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Do LEFT JOIN's instead.

Comment: I tried the left join instead of inner but it did not work ? Maybe I don't understand what you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tad dirty, but you can achieve it like this. Given that you need an article to have likes, you can `LEFT JOIN` the results from likes on the pseudo-name, grouped by the pseudo names. Use `IFNULL()` in case there are no likes on a given post.

```sql
SELECT a.pseudo, 
       a.ArticleCount, 
       IFNULL(likes, 0) as LikesCount, 
       IFNULL(likes, 0)/3 + ArticleCount as Score
FROM (
  SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(a.idArticle), 0) as ArticleCount, a.pseudo
  FROM articles a
  GROUP BY a.pseudo
) as a
-- Find all likes that user has gotten
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(l.idLike) as likes, a.pseudo
  FROM likes l
  JOIN articles a
    ON a.idArticle = l.idArticle
  GROUP BY a.pseudo
) as l
on a.pseudo=l.pseudo
```

- SQLFiddle shows the query in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/375b6f/22

Answer (score 0):

You could join the suqbeury by column pseudo

```
select t1.pseudo,t1.nbLikes, t2.nbArticle, t1.nbLikes + t2.nbArticle,
from ( 
  select  a.pseudo, count(l.idArticle) as nbLikes 
  from likes as l 
  inner join articles as a on l.idArticle = a.idArticle 
  group by a.pseudo
) t1   
left join  (
  select pseudo, count(pseudo) as nbArticle 
  from articles 
  group by pseudo
) t2 ON t1.pseudo = t2.pseudo
```

Comment: If a user has no likes on his post, he doesn't get a count for that article. This query will only give counts for posts that has at least one like. As far as I can read the original query, you want it to be +1 even if it has no likes?

Comment: Maybe I need to make more tests, but it looks like it works even if a post has no likes, at least with my data. Will try few ones to check.

Comment: See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/375b6f/22 (my query) and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0f69f/2 (this query). Rebuild the schema to put likes on articles. When an article has no likes, it won't show up - because this query joins articles on likes, instead of likes on articles. Or am I missing something vital here...?

Comment: Oh ok I get it! If someone has 0 like he won't appear at all. I was verifying that if an article has 0 like, article is still count. My bad. (Sorry, I know my english is not that good, hope you can read me easily). Thank you very much